# $_SESSION data not saved after refresh

Tags: php, session-cookies

So i have the following code that checks whether a sessions exists or not:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    echo json_encode(true);
}else{
    echo json_encode(false);
}
?>
```

The session is set from a login function in a different php file that runs a query to get the id of the user and it saves it to the session like this:

```
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

/.....

try{
            $query = "SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE (user_email=:email) AND (user_password=:password)";

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

            $email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));
            $password = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->password));

            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                $results = $stmt->fetchColumn();  
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results;
                if ( !is_writable(session_save_path()) ) {
                   echo 'Session save path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable!'; 
                }
                if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                echo "For login";
                return $stmt->errorInfo();  
            }
        }catch(Exception $e){
            die('ERROR: ' .$e->getMessage());   
        }
```

When I login for the first time it returns true and I'm redirected to the main page. But when I refresh the main page, checkSession.php returns false and i'm redirected back to the login page. I've been searching for a solution for two days and I found none. Please help

Comment: check for errors.

Comment: btw, you don't need `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags`, you're using a prepared statement.

Comment: How do i check for session errors?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php set to catch and display is a good start and possibly http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Ooh if you talking about that, there are no errors. I have a php file that does error handling that i include in all my php files